How to start my book by part 0?
This problem is similar but different from: How to start at Part 0 in LaTeX?.

I want my scrbook to start at part 0. I know that there are no Roman numerals that symbolise 0, so it's undefined when thepart=0. But what if I want to use the letter O instead of 0, what should I do then?

Locally redefine \thepart.
\documentclass{scrbook} 

\setcounter{part}{-1} % we want to start from 0

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begingroup
\renewcommand\thepart{O}
\part{Hello}   % output "O."
\endgroup

\part{World}   % output "I."

\part{Goodbye} % output "II."

\end{document}




Do you really need it?

Something like this?
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}
\setcounter{part}{14}
\part{Hello}   % output "O."

\renewcommand\thepart{\Roman{part}}
\setcounter{part}{0}
\part{World}   % output "I."

\part{Goodbye} % output "II."


\end{document}

